# S3 Deployment issues

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a jenkins pipeline, which does the following

Build
Dockerize
build and dockerize
publish to s3
deploy to ECS

During build process artifact is being generated with the assets bundled in packs folder inside public folder

There is one js file namely runtime~AggrModule-dc2bb0ab1f10f33d556d.js which is generated while bundling.

s3 is pulling the files whichever are generated in the artifact process and deploying to S3

when I tried to access the website I see that the md5sum is something else runtime~AggrModule-12bf3a4de823bb57f4e7.js which is not deployed

when try to access the URL through [https://qa-static.sf-cdn.com/library/release-20240111-0828-8f31e4d/packs/js/runtime~LibraryModule-12bf3a4de823bb57f4e7.js](https://qa-static.sf-cdn.com/library/release-20240111-0828-8f31e4d/packs/js/runtime%7ELibraryModule-12bf3a4de823bb57f4e7.js) it results in 403 forbidden error.

Why mismatch between the URLs? what is causing the issue